# Mongoose migration - how to map an array inside a collection to a new model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  trackedProducts: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectID,
      ref: 'product',
    },
  ],
});
```

And I am trying to write a migration for existing data to:

```
  const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    trackedProducts: [
      {
        productDetails: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectID,
          ref: 'product',
        },
        otherStuff: {}
      },
    ],
});
```

So effectively I want to map each value of the trackedProducts array to a more complex object in the new schema. For example, I want:

```
[objref1, objref2, objref3]
```

To be migrated to:

```
[
  { productDetails: objref1, otherStuff: {} }, 
  { productDetails: objref2, otherStuff: {}}, 
  { productDetails: objref3, otherStuff: {}}
]
```

I have been trying to play with $set along the lines of

```
await db.collection('users').update({}, { $set { <no idea> }});
```

but am unsure of a) how to go value by value of the array and b) how to get a reference to the original value.

Comment: what is your input for `otherStuff` field, you want to update other stuff as well with this query?

Comment: I omitted it for clarity but it's just another object that will initially have some default values. It's static as far as the migration is concerned. Your solution worked a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- use `updateMany()` instead of `update()`
- `$map` to iterate loop of `trackedProducts` and return with object `{ productDetails }`

```
await db.collection('users').updateMany({},
  [{
    $set: {
      trackedProducts: {
        $map: {
          input: "$trackedProducts",
          in: { productDetails: "$$this" }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```